# Convergence of a sequence.

Tags: analysis

Well I have to prove that $\{ a_{n}\}$ converges to $A$ iff $\{a_{n} -A\}$ converges to zero, and I have:

$\Rightarrow]$ We suppose that $\{ a_{n}\}$ converges to $A$, then by definition, given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $N \in J$ such that $|a_{n} -A|<\epsilon$ for $n \geq N$   and then I want to say that I propose that the $A$ in the second sequence in $A=0$ and then use the fact that $\{ a_{n}\}$ converges to $A$, Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are. If $|a_n - A|<\varepsilon$, then $|(a_n -A) - 0 |$ is also less then $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Tnank you @Antoine, and the other part is trivial isnt it?

Comment: At least I find it trivial:)

Comment: jajaja good, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:*** 
Firstly, 
$$ |a_n - A| = |(a_n - A) - 0|  $$

Now write your $\epsilon$-$N$ definitions and check why they are equivalent.